# Submitted form values not updated in model when adding <f:ajax> to <h:commandButton>

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, form-submit

I'm learning how to use ajax within jsf, I made a page that does actually nothing, an input text that is filled with a number, submitted to the server, call the setter for that element with the value submitted, and display the getter's value.

Here's the simple bean's code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="helper",eager=true)
public class HealthPlanHelper {


    String random = "1";

    public void setRandomize(String s){
        random = s;
                System.out.println("Calling setter");
    }

    public String getRandomize(){
        return random;
    }

}
```

And the jsf page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="nothing">
            <f:ajax render="num"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:inputText value="#{helper.randomize}" id="num"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

As you see, this is a request scoped bean, whenever I click the button the server shows that it creates an instance of the bean, but the setter method is never called, thus, the getter return always "1" as the value of the string.

When I remove the  the setter is called normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` processes by default only the current component ([read description of `execute` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html)). Basically, your code is exactly the same as this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="nothing">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="num"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:inputText value="#{helper.randomize}" id="num"/>
</h:form>
```

In effects, only the `<h:commandButton action>` is been processed and the `<h:inputText value>` (and any other input field, if any) is completely ignored.

You need to change the `execute` attribute to explicitly specify components or sections you'd like to process during the ajax request. Usually, in order to process the entire form, `@form` is been used:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="nothing">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="num"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:inputText value="#{helper.randomize}" id="num"/>
</h:form>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) - [Ajax (asynchronous) POST form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxPOSTForm)
- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked) (point 8)
- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces)

Comment: That worked right, does it mean that the same thing is applied to validators (not only the setter, but any process that is associated with the executed components) ?

Comment: That's correct. It affects all the phases between restore view and render response (grab request parameter, convert it, validate it, udpate model and invoke action). With `execute` you basically control which components should be processed during the form submit. Note that in e.g. PrimeFaces this already defaults to `@form` (and they renamed `execute` to `process` (and `render` to `update`) which makes IMO more sense).